# Confusion regarding which formula to use?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I have started learning Permutation and Combination. In that I have some confusion regarding Combination with repetitions.
Here's one question that i tried to do

How many solutions does this equation have in the non-negative integers?
$$a+b+c=100$$
The formula for Combination with repetition is \begin{pmatrix}
  n+r-1\\
  r\\
\end{pmatrix}
So by above formula the answer should be \begin{pmatrix}
102\\3
   \end{pmatrix}
But the answer is \begin{pmatrix}
102\\2
\end{pmatrix}
Please help

EDIT:

Source of the problem

[https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/zju/math/perm-comb-more.html](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/%7Eggbaker/zju/math/perm-comb-more.html)

Comment: Perhaps it's because you don't have three choices, you only have two. Once you have chosen $a$ and $b$, then $c$ is automatically determined as $c=100 - a - b$.

Comment: Please write an *informative* (and searchable) title that relates to the content of your question.

Comment: Correct formula is $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ because we have to choose $r-1$ separators.

Comment: Yes!! I get the correct answer if I use the above formula.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use the formula for combinations with repetition, but then you need to swap $n$ and $k$ in your solution.

You have $100$ elements of $3$ kinds to choose, with potential (and actually unavoidable!) repetition. (Take $a$, $b$ and $c$ to be the number of chosen elements of the first, second and third kind, respectively.) Thus, the formula is, for $n=3$ and $k=100$: ${3+100-1 \choose 100}={102\choose 100}$, which is the same as ${102\choose 2}$.

Comment: The formula is wrong I think...The correct one is $C(n+r−1,r)=C(n+r−1,n−1)$

Comment: https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/zju/math/perm-comb-more.html

Comment: @AkshajJumde Not sure what you are trying to say. What you've written boils down to ${102\choose 100}={102\choose 2}$. The $2$ below is $n-1$, as $n=3$. In your solution you assumed $n=100$ - that was the mistake.

Comment: So $n \neq 100$ ?

Comment: Indeed. You are picking $100$ objects from a set of $3$, with repetition; *not* $3$ objects from a set of $100$ - so $n=3, k=100$.

Answer (score 1):

Line up your numbers $1,2,3,\ldots 100$.  Imagine placing two vertical bars, between successive integers, e.g., $1,2,3|4,5,\ldots,63,64|65,\ldots 100$.  That corresponds to the case of $a = 3$, $b = 61$, and $c = 36$.  Do you see why?

How many places can you place the first vertical bar?  (Note you can put it *before* the $1$ or *after* the $100$.  How many places can you place the *second* vertical bar?  Note that you have overcounted by a factor of $2$ because you could have chosen them in the reverse order.

And sooo.....

Comment: This seems like Stars and Bars https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)